# handling zombie process status

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, process, zombie-process

I am new to scripting. I am writing a process status monitor script that should catch when a process gets killed, zombied or sleeping etc. I am not sure this is really a good script, if any better alternatives are there pls suggest.

For the problem I am facing, below script can catch the status running, sleeping, stopped etc. But for the zombie process, we see two pids for the command `pidof zombie`. which is getting treated as error and the script does not catch that status.

Can anyone suggest how to catch the zombie state of the process.

By the way, I have created a zombie process whose status can be seen as zombie for sometime on the shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

do_start() {
    # List of process names to be monitored for its termination/killing.
    declare -a PROCESS_LIST
    PROCESS_LIST=("process_1" "process_2" "zombie")
    for process in "${PROCESS_LIST[@]}"; do
        echo "checking for $process"
        pid=$(pidof $process)
        echo "its pid is $pid"
        if [ $pid ]; then
            pid_status=`head /proc/$pid/status | grep "State:*"`
            echo $pid_status
            if [[ "$pid_status" =~ .*"sleeping"*. ]] || [[ "$pid_status" =~ .*"stopped"*. ]] || [[ "$pid_status" =~ .*"running"*. ]]; then
                echo "process:$process with pid $pid is having status $pid_status"
            elif [[ "$pid_status" =~ .*"zombie"*. ]]; then
                echo "process:$process with pid $pid is having status $pid_status"
            fi
        else
            echo "pid not present" > /dev/null
        fi
    done
}

while :
do
    do_start
    sleep 2
done
```

**OUTPUT**:

> checking for process_1
> its pid is 12668
> State: S (sleeping)
> process:process_1 with pid 12668 is having status State:        S (sleeping)
> checking for zombie
> its pid is 12818 12817
> ./process_monitor.sh: line 13: [: 12818: unary operator expected

> checking for process_1
> its pid is 12668
> State: R (running)
> process:process_1 with pid 12668 is having status State:        R (running)
> checking for zombie
> its pid is 12818 12817
> ./process_monitor.sh: line 13: [: 12818: unary operator expected

**$ ps ux  output**

```
xolo    12668 95.3  0.0   4164   360 pts/4    R    15:32   0:07 ./process_1  
xolo    12817  0.0  0.0   4160   360 pts/4    S    15:32   0:00 ./zombie  
xolo    12818  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/4    Z    15:32   0:00 [zombie]<defunct>
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I have not read the entire question too deeply. That said... Some zombie processes may be necessary; A parent process may have not yet reaped a zombied child process so it can inspect the result/return code. The parent may malfunction if you terminate/kill it and the parent later tries to reap it. If you are having trouble with too many unreaped zombies, you should look in to _why_, and which parent process is running around trying to kickstart a virtual Zombie Apocalypse--and fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not related to the zombie status but to the fact that `pidof` returns the pids of all processes running the named program. The child of your `zombie` program is also called `zombie`, so both pids are printed.

`pidof` has an option `-s` which tells it to return only one pid. Alternatively, you could enumerate the pids returned and check each in turn.